# integrate bootstrap accordion and gallery with old database gallery in asp-classic

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vbscript, asp-classic

I am trying to renew a site done in asp-classic, and integrate it with bootstrap. I successfully changed the table layout with the bootstrap grid layout.
I have a gallery page that needs to be merged, and I need some help in creating the database result `loop` for the bootstrap accordion panel component.

I have managed to get the panels heading to pull the data from database, and display it, but for the panels' content I am lost.
I tried some using some of the old code, but keep geting errors, like expected wend, or similar.

I know part of the old code is unnecessary for the bootstrap panel display, as the old code would create pages to be displayed, whereas in the new look all would be in the same page.

I need to change the way data from database is displayed.
You may see the old and new here:

fioriera. com/Galleria-Foto.asp
fioriera. com/new/galleria-foto.asp

This is the relevant code of new galleria-foto.asp file, part of which is still as the old one stripped from the table layout, and what I need help to rearrange (recode) for my purpose - further below the old file.

```
<!-- content area -->
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="fz-main-content-wrap">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 fz-home-main">
                    <div class="fz-home-box">
                        <h1>galleria</h1>
<% 
    '################################################################################
        IF Request.QueryString("testo") = "" THEN
    '################################################################################
%>

    <!-- #include file="_apri.asp" --><%
    strSQL = "SELECT tbl_testi.*, tbl_foto.* FROM tbl_testi LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_foto ON tbl_testi.riftesto = tbl_foto.riftesto "
    strSQL = strSQL + "WHERE (tbl_foto.principale = 1 OR tbl_foto.principale IS null) AND tbl_testi.tipo = 'foto' ORDER BY data DESC"
    SET objRS = objConn.Execute(strSQL) %>

<% IF objRS.EOF THEN %>
    <div align="center">Sezione in aggiornamento.<br>
    Torna presto a trovarci o <a target="_top" href="Contatti-Informazioni-Ordini.asp">contattaci</a>.
    </div>

<% ELSE %>

<% i = 1 %>
<div aria-multiselectable="true" class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist">
<% WHILE NOT objRS.EOF %>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading clearfix" id="heading_<%=i %>" role="tab">
            <div class="col-md-8 fz-2">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
            <%=objRS("data")%><br>
            <a aria-controls="collapse_<%=i %>" aria-expanded="true" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse_<%=i %>" role="button">
            <%=objRS("titolo")%>
            </a>
            </h4>
            </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 fz-2">
            <% IF LEN(objRS("idchiave")) > 1 THEN %>
                    <img class="img-responsive" name="img" src="public/<%=objRS("idchiave")%>" />
                <% ELSE %>
                    (No Foto)
                <% END IF %>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div aria-labelledby="heading_<%=i %>" class="panel-collapse collapse<% If i = 1 Then %> in<% End If %>" id="collapse_<%=i %>" role="tabpanel">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="fz-gallery-wrap">

                Here should be the loop to output the images of each category (item i.e. fioriera rovere 202 etc.)

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<% i = i + 1 %>
<% objRS.MoveNext %>
<% WEND %>
</div>

<!-- #include file="_chiudi2.asp" -->
<% END IF %>

<% 
    '################################################################################
        ELSE
    '################################################################################
%>

<a href="galleria-foto.asp">Clicca qui per tornare alla lista</a>

    <h2 align="center"><%= Request.QueryString("titolo") %></h2>
    <br>

<p style="text-align:justify">
<%
    Set objFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    strFileX = Application("path_public") + "\" + Request.QueryString("testo") + ".txt"
    Set objFILE = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileX, 1)
    WHILE NOT objFILE.AtEndOfStream
        Response.Write (objFILE.ReadLine)
    WEND
    objFILE.Close
    Set objFILE = Nothing
    Set objFSO = Nothing
%>
</p>

<br>
<p style="text-align:center">(clicca sulle foto per ingrandirle)</p>

<!-- #include file="_apri.asp" --><%
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_foto WHERE riftesto = '" + Request.QueryString("testo") + "'"
set objRS = objConn.Execute(strSQL) %>

<% i=1 %>
<% WHILE NOT objRS.EOF %>

        <div class="row fz-3">
        <div class="col-md-9 fz-4 didascalia">
                    <%= objRS("didascalia")%>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 fz-2">

            <a href="public/<%=objRS("idchiave")%>">
            <img class="img-responsive" name="img<%=i%>" border="0" src="public/<%=objRS("idchiave")%>" alt='<%= objRS("didascalia")%>' /></a>

                     </div>
                     </div>

<% i = i + 1 %>
<% objRS.MoveNext %>
<% WEND %>
<!-- #include file="_chiudi2.asp" -->

    <div align="center">
        <a href="galleria-foto.asp">Clicca qui per tornare alla lista</a>
    </div>

<% 
    '################################################################################
        END IF
    '################################################################################
%>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 fz-home-main">
                <aside id="sidebar">
                    <div class="row">

                    </div>
                    </aside>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- .fz-main-content-wrap -->
    </div><!-- .container -->
</section>
<!-- END content area -->
```

Old Galleria-Foto.asp file

```
<div align="center">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse">
        <tr>
            <td width="580" valign="top">
<% 
    '################################################################################
        IF Request.QueryString("testo") = "" THEN
    '################################################################################
%>
    <div align="center">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td><hr style="height: 1px; color: #000099;"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <!-- #include file="_apri.asp" --><%
    strSQL = "SELECT tbl_testi.*, tbl_foto.* FROM tbl_testi LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_foto ON tbl_testi.riftesto = tbl_foto.riftesto "
    strSQL = strSQL + "WHERE (tbl_foto.principale = 1 OR tbl_foto.principale IS null) AND tbl_testi.tipo = 'foto' ORDER BY data DESC"
    SET objRS = objConn.Execute(strSQL) %>

<% IF objRS.EOF THEN %>
    <div align="center">Sezione in aggiornamento.<br>
    Torna presto a trovarci o <a target="_top" href="Contatti-Informazioni-Ordini.asp">contattaci</a>.
    </div>

<% ELSE %>

    <div align="center">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="100%">
<% i = 1 %>
<% WHILE NOT objRS.EOF %>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 450px; height: 85px; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                <%=objRS("data")%><br>
                <a href="galleria-foto.asp?testo=<%=objRS("tbl_testi.riftesto")%>&titolo=<%=objRS("titolo")%>&data=<%=objRS("data")%>"><%=objRS("titolo")%></a>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 110px; height: 85px;">
                <% IF LEN(objRS("idchiave")) > 1 THEN %>
                    <iframe name="Foto<%=i%>" src='Galleria-Foto-TUMB.asp?foto=<%=objRS("idchiave")%>&amp;base=100&amp;altezza=75' border="0" frameborder="0" height="77" marginheight="1" marginwidth="1" width="102" scrolling="no"></iframe>
                <% ELSE %>
                    (No Foto)
                <% END IF %>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><hr style="height: 1px; color: #000099;"></td>
            </tr>
<% i = i + 1 %>
<% objRS.MoveNext %>
<% WEND %>
        </table>
    </div>

<!-- #include file="_chiudi2.asp" -->
<% END IF %>

<% 
    '################################################################################
        ELSE
    '################################################################################
%>

      <div align="center">
                <table style="width: 500px; height: 30px; border: 1px solid #000099;">
               <tr>
                  <td align="center"><a href="galleria-foto.asp">Clicca qui per tornare alla lista</a></td>
               </tr>
            </table>
      </div>

    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <h2 align="center"><%= Request.QueryString("titolo") %></h2>
    <br>

<p style="text-align:justify">
<%
    Set objFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    strFileX = Application("path_public") + "\" + Request.QueryString("testo") + ".txt"
    Set objFILE = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileX, 1)
    WHILE NOT objFILE.AtEndOfStream
        Response.Write (objFILE.ReadLine)
    WEND
    objFILE.Close
    Set objFILE = Nothing
    Set objFSO = Nothing
%>
</p>

<br>
<p style="text-align:center">(clicca sulle foto per ingrandirle)</p>

<!-- #include file="_apri.asp" --><%
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_foto WHERE riftesto = '" + Request.QueryString("testo") + "'"
set objRS = objConn.Execute(strSQL) %>

    <div align="center">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td><hr style="height: 1px; color: #000099;"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

<% i=1 %>
<% WHILE NOT objRS.EOF %>

    <div align="center">
        <table border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse">
            <tr>
                <td width="250" height="170" align="center">
                    <%= objRS("didascalia")%>
                </td>

                <td width="250" height="180" align="center">

<!--                    <iframe name="Foto<%=i%>" src='galleria-foto-FOTO.asp?foto=<%=objRS("idchiave")%>&base=248&altezza=178&didascalia=<%= objRS("didascalia")%>' frameborder="0" height="180" marginheight="1" marginwidth="1" width="250" scrolling="no"></iframe> -->

            <a href="public/<%=objRS("idchiave")%>" rel="lightbox[foto]">
            <img name="img<%=i%>" border="0" src="public/<%=objRS("idchiave")%>" alt='<%= objRS("didascalia")%>'
            onload="if (img<%=i%>.width/img<%=i%>.height < 250/180) {if (img<%=i%>.height > 180 ) {img<%=i%>.height= 180;} } else {if (img<%=i%>.width > 250 ) {img<%=i%>.width= 250;} }" 
            onmouseover="if (img<%=i%>.width/img<%=i%>.height < 250/180) {if (img<%=i%>.height > 180 ) {img<%=i%>.height= 180;} } else {if (img<%=i%>.width > 250 ) {img<%=i%>.width= 250;} }"                   
                     ></a>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div align="center">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td><hr style="height: 1px; color: #000099;"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

<% i = i + 1 %>
<% objRS.MoveNext %>
<% WEND %>
<!-- #include file="_chiudi2.asp" -->

      <div align="center">
                <table style="width: 500px; height: 30px; border: 1px solid #000099;">
               <tr>
                  <td align="center" style="height: 26px"><a href="galleria-foto.asp">Clicca qui per tornare alla lista</a></td>
               </tr>
            </table>
      </div>

<% 
    '################################################################################
        END IF
    '################################################################################
%>
            </td>
            <td width="5">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The included files _apri.asp _chiudi1.asp _chiudi2.asp are the db open/close connection snips.

I tried many combinations of moving snips, but all I get are errors.
Original thank you removed because some people don't like to be thanked for their contribution.

*EDIT*
Database details (table-name - [fields])

```
tbl_foto [riftesto - idchiave - principale - didascalia]
tbl_testi [riftesto - data - titolo - giorni - tipo]
tbl_tipi [tipo - att_didascalia - att_foto - att_testo - descrizione]
```

Translation of fields to clarify

riftesto - text reference

idchiave - id key

principale - main (is the panel heading image set to 1 if main 0 if not)

didascalia - caption

data - date

titolo - title

giorni - days

tipo - type

foto - picture (image)

descrizione - description

att_ - really don't know what the original coder meant, but I think is irrelevant to the use.

Comment: I edited the question, and title. from the help center link provide I read: "When a question reaches 5 close votes, it is marked [on hold]" and here I see 3 votes, I consider this an abuse, and not in line with the "site quality" argumentation.

Comment: let's go with the flow, we spend too much time reading negative comments that didn't lead anywhere. I really didn't see an issue with your question, might be due to the fact I coded in Italia for years. Your question has evolved beyond the Bootstrap which means it's time for you to post a new Question. Maybe, if you read profiles we could get you going down the correct path. You have to let this post close, so do it yourself, mark the answer if it helps and post a follow up question. We're not going to do your code but we can give you many tips. I'm programming today so just ask.

Comment: @MurrayW you are now actively encouraging the OP to open more questions? That will then be three questions they have posted about the same issue, why because the subject matter is too board! If the scope has changed...change the question not open a new one!

Comment: The first question was how to place the bootstrap accordion with a gallery inside the old ASP code. He posted the code, I removed everything from the old code that wasn't needed in a ASP Classic Bootstrap website. He posted it online and it worked. Then he edited my post thinking that he was going to create a SQL Data lookup loop by moving HTML. This showed me he doesn't see the big picture. To clearly divide HTML and ASP I asked to setup a new post for only his ASP Code, I commented that the question was not worded correctly and that I would change it once he has his answer.

Comment: It doesn't take a genius to see what he is doing. We all have done Bootstrap upgrades to themes. I run @htmlstream themes which are very detailed on some very old ASP Sites. Let's say you stop fighting this process and stop with the downgrades. All you are doing is showing others this is not the place to find help. You can edit questions, why don't you do it instead of spending our time fighting who's understanding what. I thought this was a good place to share information and to help interpret questions. Guess you know better than me I'll take this over to my Google+ account.

Comment: @Lankymart I am not sure why are you trying to make it hard to solve my issue, as you can see from the comments, I did not sit waiting for Murray to feed me - your first objection - now that's not the case you are trying to find other excuses. You then say the question is too broad, but if I make it into pieces, and post specific questions you say they are on the same subject. I think you are going out of your way in your crusade. Just think the time we all are spending (wasting?). You don't like to help me? fine, no problem, why are you making it hard to others if they are willing to do so?

Comment: Look I'm sick of trying to explain this isn't rent a coder. It's clear you don't understand the code you are posting. I tried to explain that this isn't the place for these types of questions. @MurrayW you are actively encouraging them which is disappointing, all the questions are about setting up a bootstrap accordion in Classic ASP which isn't a specific enough, this will likely get closed soon enough along with your other duplicates.

Comment: @Lankymart I am glad I made your day. Feels good to belittle someone, right? You are not only born knowledgeable, you can also decide what a person understands, and what doesn't, you go beyond genius, you are close to a Prophet. Enjoy your greatness, it'll all be gone one day, and all will be left is your points here at SO to testify it.

Comment: Points? What are you on about? There are user here with 100k+??

Comment: @Lankymart I am not on about anything, I didn't see any of those 100K+ (BTW it should be capitalized K) make such a fuss about this question. I take my word back, you are not all knowledgeable, you need to learn some humbleness.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have much work to do in your project. 
Team up with an ASP Classic person. (We number in the millions)

From our long conversation my answer is short regarding layout and how you might be able to get things working.

How to get the layout above with the code provided?

**Our flow**

1. Date objRS("data")
2. Title objRS("titolo")
3. Thumbnail for category galleria-foto.asp?testo=<%=objRS("riftesto")%> example: www.domain.ext/galleria-foto.asp?testo=141231654418504130 (I'm guessing)
4. Gallery thumbnails created Galleria-Foto-TUMB.asp?foto=<%=objRS("idchiave")%> example: www.domain.ext/Galleria-Foto-TUMB.asp?foto=141231656428504969.JPG

Basically all you are asking is to show you with your own code where you would need to place your HTML code to make the desired results of an accordion with gallery view.

I am going to simplify this because of some old code. 
This also means we need to update our JS and CSS if we are going to use the LightBox javascript features.
(Again, I'm NOT editing ASP Code only placing HTML within your ASP Script)

```
<div aria-multiselectable="true" class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist">

        <!-- #include file="_apri.asp" -->
        <%
        strSQL = "SELECT tbl_testi.*, tbl_foto.* FROM tbl_testi LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_foto ON tbl_testi.riftesto = tbl_foto.riftesto "
        strSQL = strSQL + "WHERE (tbl_foto.principale = 1 OR tbl_foto.principale IS null) AND tbl_testi.tipo = 'foto' ORDER BY data DESC"
        SET objRS = objConn.Execute(strSQL)
        IF objRS.EOF THEN
        %>
        <!-- do your html message for nothing found.-->
        <% Else %>
        <% i = 1 %>


        <% WHILE NOT objRS.EOF%>
            <% IF LEN(objRS("idchiave")) > 1 THEN %>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading clearfix" id="heading_<%=i %>" role="tab">
            <div class="col-md-8 fz-2">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
            <%=objRS("data")%><br>
            <a aria-controls="collapse_<%=i %>" aria-expanded="true" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse_<%=i %>" role="button">
            <%=objRS("titolo")%>
            </a>
            </h4>
            </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 fz-2">         
                    <% IF LEN(objRS("idchiave")) > 1 THEN %>
                    <img class="img-responsive" alt="img" src="/public/<%=objRS("idchiave")%>" />
                    <% ELSE %>
                    (No Foto)
                    <% END IF %>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div aria-labelledby="heading_<%=i %>" class="panel-collapse collapse<% If i = 1 Then %> in<% End If %>" id="collapse_<%=i %>" role="tabpanel">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="fz-gallery-wrap">
                        <a href="/public/<%=objRS("idchiave")%>" rel="gallery" class="" data-lightbox="Group-<%=objRS("idchiave")%>" 
                        data-title="Image-<%=i%>: Title for Image-<%=i%>" 
                        title="Image-<%=i%>: Title for Image-<%=i%>">
                            <img src="/public/<%=objRS("idchiave")%>" width="150px" alt="Image-<%=i%>: Title for Image-<%=i%>" />
                        </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <%End If%>
        <% i = i + 1 %>
        <% objRS.MoveNext %>
    <% WEND %>

    <% 
    End If 'objRS.EOF
    %>

        <!-- #include file="_chiudi2.asp" -->
</div>
```

This is the same code as the sample page that I posted for you. 
Most all of the code you shared will not be needed. 
You have your IF strFoto which only creates a thumbnail and your other code that creates your IFRAME are in my opinion no longer needed.

You may like it better by allowing the images to free form to your single column. 
In my cases I use both, as long as you have CSS for your img class="image_design" that will make it look like it's ordered you will be fine.

This will get you going down your long path. 
You are a coder, you knew just what code to publish. 
It's hard reading others code, I use thousands of call functions to make it next to impossible to follow the flow.

Relax, your question was, "How do I place Bootstrap Accordion and Gallery features into my old ASP Classic Gallery page."

I'll update as you test to better document the process. I'll also publish another way so when you search you find your post and mine. :)

NOTE: I did not test the ASP code, not sure if I have your table names correctly identified but I did test the HTML layout and function on my site.

Comment: I'll detail the results later, I gotta run, this is just to thank you. If they close the question, and I'll be unable to post (don't know how it works), please contact me with my username @gmail.com

Comment: I did use your code, and deleted all other asp code outside the accordion, and I get this error: `ADODB.Recordset error '800a0cc1'
Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal.` The line is the heading image `<img class="img-responsive" alt="img" src="<%=objRS(" idchiave")%>" />`, which I guess is generated from the SELECT line, and it prevents further loading of page. I'll edit OP to add the db details.

Comment: Now it's time for your debugging of your ASP Code which is not related to the question. I want to make sure people don't have that "American Cow" they talk about because you and I drift off the original question.I see a SPACE in the objRS(" idchiave") if that is true remove the space and try again. I edited my posting and because you are so close I'll walk you through this one page... If it doesn't hurt to much. (humor)

Comment: @keneso, your edit update to your post changes the question. Keep it related to your Bootstrap and mark it answered if it answered your Bootstrap question. ASP Errors are unrelated. Take your edits and errors to a new post this time asking for help on ASP SQL . We all try to get as much info from one post we often loose focus. Layout, HTML Bootstrap has been answered, tested. Now you need to debug your ASP Classic code. Post another question about your code listed what you edited above. View profiles for examples of work and don't let things get to you. Keep focused.

Comment: Thanks Murray. I got the images to display in the first panel. But all the categories main images no other panels. Here are the steps I made. There were more instances of the idchiave with leading space, then the line `" rel="gallery" class="" data-lightbox="Group-<%=objRS("riftesto")%>"` caused errors, I put each piece of code on one line till I got the `<%=objRS("riftesto")%>"` I changed it with idchiave, and images display, but like said instead of different panels each with its own images, the main images are shown in the only panel. ... continue ...

Comment: ... continue ... I moved some of the code, and I see the panels, but no headings, I'll play some more to see if I can manage it. I guess it's just where to move the code in the html flow. Will update.

Comment: Ok fixed the accordion loop. The issue now is with retriving the images to display. I created new question [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35753467/bootstrap-accordion-and-asp-classic-loop-not-generating-the-expected-content[link]. I will edit your post so the solution is correct for others.

Comment: Great, edit all that you need. I noticed the category image not displaying. Add /public/ /public/<%=objRS("idchiave")%> to make that work. I missed that.

Comment: @Keneso, you got me thinking the student is testing the master. The edit was rejected which is good. You are missing the point of my post. It is for one complete category with subcategories. It is not your main master category index. That's building on your other question. Leave this as it is, you will see soon how it all comes together. Grasshopper.